# What are some USB 2.0 Redirect Options for Windows 2003 Server Terminal Service?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

Currently we are using HP thin clients to remote desktop into a set of Win2k3 servers.  We would like to redirect the USB ports from the thin clients to Win2k3.  The issue is that the software loaded on the thin clients (and sister software for the servers) does not work with Win2k3.  This leaves us looking for other options to handle USB redirection on Win2k3.  I am interested in hearing from the community suggestions as to what software we could use to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been using USB over Network for attaching Windows 2003 VMs to remote USB devices (Security dongles mainly) and it works pretty well. They have a version that is tuned for thin clients but I haven't used it.
http://www.usb-over-network.com/

They claim to support the following platforms:

USB for Remote Desktop Server

32-bit: Windows Vista / XP / 2000 / Server 2003 / Server 2008

64-bit: Windows Vista / XP / Server 2003 / Server 2008

USB for Remote Desktop Workstation

32-bit: Windows Vista / XP / 2000 / Server 2003 / Server 2008

64-bit: Windows Vista / XP / Server 2003 / Server 2008

Linux kernel 2.6.12 or greater

Windows CE (ARM, MIPS, SH3, SH4 and x86)